# I'm getting dozens of "Failed loading" errors in cgi_error_log daily - what do they mean?

Tags: error-log

I'm seeing dozens of entries, daily, in my cgi_error_log file like this:

```
20151214T183710: www.example/index.php
Failed loading /usr/local/lib/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.2.so:  /usr/local/lib/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.2.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
Failed loading /usr/local/Zend/lib/ZendExtensionManager.so:  /usr/local/Zend/lib/ZendExtensionManager.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
```

I changed the URL in the error message because the site is not yet ready for the public and I don't want any links to the site or even text in posts like this laying around.

As the site is still in testing, these messages are coming from my accessing pages and all of the pages have loaded correctly.

What does this message mean? I have no clue other than that ioncube is some sort of PHP Encoder.

Could this have something to do with the 32bit version of ioncube being run on a 64bit system? I've found references to that sort of problem.

Did some more digging - could this be happening because the version of PHP on the server is not 5.2? Error about ioncube shows 4.2 in the file name.

The version I'm using on the server if 5.5. They have 5.3 and 5.6.

If they had 5.2 I'd give it a try but it is not available.

More digging - found this set in my php.ini file for all my sites.

```
[Zend]
zend_extension = /usr/local/lib/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.2.so
zend_extension_manager.optimizer=/usr/local/Zend/lib/Optimizer-3.2.0
zend_extension_manager.optimizer_ts=/usr/local/Zend/lib/Optimizer_TS-3.2.0
zend_optimizer.version=3.2.0
zend_extension=/usr/local/Zend/lib/ZendExtensionManager.so
zend_extension_ts=/usr/local/Zend/lib/ZendExtensionManager_TS.so
```

So - do I need to install newer versions of one or more of the items listed above?

If so - where do I start and can I do it myself or does the hosting company staff have to do it?

Comment: The server you are running is 64-bit while the libraries are 32-bit, hence the error `wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32`. Try installing the 64-bit versions of these libraries instead. You may also check if these libraries come in both bitness by checking for `/usr/local/lib64/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.2.so` and `/usr/local/Zend/lib64/*.so`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply -   That is one  of the thing I came across, Just as a reality check - we ARE talking server, not client (my system) - right?   The server is that of a hosting company. If it were my server I would dive right into it (having backed up everything) but given that it's not my server, do you think the hosting company will do the install? I would think they would given that it can't be working for any sites on the server, but you never know for sure. I'll contact hosting support and see what they have to say - again, thanks for the reply.